# Can I create Page Tab through Graph API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am currently developing an web application on Rails. I want the user to be able to create his own facebook page. I thought of creating custom Tab for him on my main application or page.

Can Graph API create Page Tabs programatically?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that it is possible to actually *create* a new application via the API. This would open a flood gate for possible spam.

What you will be able to do is allow users to add your tab application to their page and then provide them with some customization. You can add a tab to a page programmatically with a post call similar to this -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs
```

along with these parameters -

- `app_id` - Tab application to be added.
- `access_token` - An access token with permissions to manage the page (`manage_pages`).

References -

- [Pages Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs)
- [Permisssions Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)

Comment: Can I create tabs on my application? each tab can represent a person, and all people will be tabs on my application. Is that possible? I am sorry but I am noob GraphAPI user.

Comment: You'll have to go over your terminology again. You don't add tabs to applications. Tabs **are** applications, tab applications. You can only add these items to a Facebook **page**. I don't think it is wise to have a separate tab for each user. Just have one and customize it according to who is viewing it. You can get information on the current user via the `signed_request` that is passed to the application.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. I still need to create separate pages, I need each page to display certain content regardless of the person who is viewing it.